# How to get all addresses and masks from local interfaces in go?

Tags: networking, go, ip, ip-address

How can I get all addresses and masks from local interfaces in golang?

I need the actual network mask configured along with every IP address.

This code does not show the network masks in Windows 7:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net"
)

func localAddresses() {
    ifaces, err := net.Interfaces()
    if err != nil {
        log.Print(fmt.Errorf("localAddresses: %v\n", err.Error()))
        return
    }
    for _, i := range ifaces {
        addrs, err := i.Addrs()
        if err != nil {
            log.Print(fmt.Errorf("localAddresses: %v\n", err.Error()))
            continue
        }
        for _, a := range addrs {
            log.Printf("%v %v\n", i.Name, a)
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    localAddresses()
}
```

UPDATE: This issue has been fixed in Go: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/5395

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are multiply types of addresses that a `net.Interface` might have. The `Addr` is just an interface which may contain a `net.IPAddr`. But with a type assertion or type switch you can access the actual address type:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net"
)

func localAddresses() {
    ifaces, err := net.Interfaces()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Print(fmt.Errorf("localAddresses: %+v\n", err.Error()))
        return
    }
    for _, i := range ifaces {
        addrs, err := i.Addrs()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Print(fmt.Errorf("localAddresses: %+v\n", err.Error()))
            continue
        }
        for _, a := range addrs {
            switch v := a.(type) {
            case *net.IPAddr:
                fmt.Printf("%v : %s (%s)\n", i.Name, v, v.IP.DefaultMask())
            }

        }
    }
}

func main() {
    localAddresses()
}
```

**Edit**

Unfortunately the `net` package doesn't return the Mask of the address. So, you will have to do the low level syscalls that the `net` package does. The code below is an example, but parsing of the ip and the mask still needs to be done:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net"
    "os"
    "syscall"
    "unsafe"
)

func getAdapterList() (*syscall.IpAdapterInfo, error) {
    b := make([]byte, 1000)
    l := uint32(len(b))
    a := (*syscall.IpAdapterInfo)(unsafe.Pointer(&b[0]))
    // TODO(mikio): GetAdaptersInfo returns IP_ADAPTER_INFO that
    // contains IPv4 address list only. We should use another API
    // for fetching IPv6 stuff from the kernel.
    err := syscall.GetAdaptersInfo(a, &l)
    if err == syscall.ERROR_BUFFER_OVERFLOW {
        b = make([]byte, l)
        a = (*syscall.IpAdapterInfo)(unsafe.Pointer(&b[0]))
        err = syscall.GetAdaptersInfo(a, &l)
    }
    if err != nil {
        return nil, os.NewSyscallError("GetAdaptersInfo", err)
    }
    return a, nil
}

func localAddresses() error {
    ifaces, err := net.Interfaces()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    aList, err := getAdapterList()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    for _, ifi := range ifaces {
        for ai := aList; ai != nil; ai = ai.Next {
            index := ai.Index

            if ifi.Index == int(index) {
                ipl := &ai.IpAddressList
                for ; ipl != nil; ipl = ipl.Next {

                    fmt.Printf("%s: %s (%s)\n", ifi.Name, ipl.IpAddress, ipl.IpMask)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return err
}

func main() {
    err := localAddresses()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

*Some code shamelessly borrowed from interface_windows.go. Even comments are left intact*

Comment: I need the actual mask, not the classful default. I see the type net.IPNet provides net.IPNet.Mask. Is there a way to read the addresses as net.IPNet instead?

Comment: Looking at the docs/source for the `net` package, I see they only provide the IP. So, what you would have to do is using the `syscall` package instead. I will update my answer.

Comment: Nice! However it's only showing addresses/masks for one interface. Fixed here: http://play.golang.org/p/kJ0P7HnvDE Please update the answer then I am accepting it! Thanks.

Comment: @Everton Ah, yes. I see my mistake. I've updated the code with your bug-fix. Welcome :)

Comment: syscall.IpAdapterInfo has some issue on Go 1.5, it will fixed in Go 1.6. Refer github.com/golang/go/issues/12551

Answer (score 9):

I'm modifying @ANisus answer and get all interfaces & masks (tested on Windows 10 & WSL in it (Microsoft Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net"
)

func localAddresses() {
    ifaces, err := net.Interfaces()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Print(fmt.Errorf("localAddresses: %+v\n", err.Error()))
        return
    }
    for _, i := range ifaces {
        addrs, err := i.Addrs()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Print(fmt.Errorf("localAddresses: %+v\n", err.Error()))
            continue
        }
        for _, a := range addrs {
            switch v := a.(type) {
            case *net.IPAddr:
                fmt.Printf("%v : %s (%s)\n", i.Name, v, v.IP.DefaultMask())

            case *net.IPNet:
                fmt.Printf("%v : %s [%v/%v]\n", i.Name, v, v.IP, v.Mask)
            }

        }
    }
}

func main() {
    localAddresses()
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This should give you the `ipnet` you're looking for.

```
ip, ipnet, err := net.ParseCIDR(a.String())
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this post for Windows 7, but if you use Mac OS X hope this could help you.

Just Call `GetNetMask("en0")`

```
func GetNetMask(deviceName string) string {
    switch runtime.GOOS {
    case "darwin":
        cmd := exec.Command("ipconfig", "getoption", deviceName, "subnet_mask")
        out, err := cmd.CombinedOutput()
        if err != nil {
            return ""
        }

        nm := strings.Replace(string(out), "\n", "", -1)
        log.Println("netmask=", nm, " OS=", runtime.GOOS)
        return nm
    default:
        return ""
    }
    return ""
}
```